# Advanced mysql query to find items to complete groups of items

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, logic

I'm trying to do an advanced numeric selection based on a specific criteria.
I have a list of paintings, each one has N colors on it. I have only few specific colors.
DB is super easy: a table for paintings (id-name), a table for paintings (id-name) and a table to link colours and paintings (painting_id - colour_id)

[Playground with DB and query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6RUwTyjkHVNwZTeAjGKYiE/0)

My problem #1 was to find paintings that I could "draw" with the colours in my possession.
I did it using this query (I assume I have colors 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14):

```
SELECT sub1.painting_id AS id FROM
(
  SELECT painting_id, count(color_id) AS tot FROM painting_colors GROUP BY painting_id
) AS sub1,
(
  SELECT painting_id, count(color_id) AS matched FROM painting_colors WHERE color_id IN(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14) GROUP BY painting_id
) AS sub2
WHERE sub1.painting_id = sub2.painting_id AND (tot - matched) = 0
```

This works very well, but now I'm trying to find which colour I should "buy" to be able to paint the greatest number of paintings that I couldn't draw without it.

A wrong way to accomplish this was searching the most used colour that I don't have, with this query:

```
SELECT color_id, count(*) FROM painting_colors WHERE color_id NOT IN(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14) GROUP BY color_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

but I know it's wrong because it would suggest me the most used colours, not the one I need to complete paintings, that could be even very rare paintings.

The only thing that came in my mind is a brute-force using the first query adding one different color_id each time to see the count of paintings that can be done, in the end I order these counts and I'll find the most wanted colour, but I guess this is very poor performing and I'm sure there is a smarter way..

Step 1 could be finding every painting with a discard of missing colours of 1, like the first query but changing count like that

```
(tot - matched) = 1
```

after that, I'm lost

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once you have a query that tells you how many colors you lack for each painting, you should be able to reduce that to only the paintings where you lack exactly one, then you can join it back to get which color you lack for each painting, and get a count.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, also thanks to @Jerry

```
SELECT 
    color_id, COUNT(*) AS would_unlock_paintings
FROM painting_colors
WHERE painting_id IN 
(
    SELECT sub1.painting_id AS id FROM
    (
        SELECT painting_id, count(color_id) AS tot FROM painting_colors GROUP BY painting_id
    ) AS sub1,
    (
        SELECT painting_id, count(color_id) AS matched FROM painting_colors WHERE color_id IN(2,4,5,7,9,11,12,13,15,17,18) GROUP BY painting_id
    ) AS sub2
    WHERE sub1.painting_id = sub2.painting_id AND tot - matched = 1
)
AND color_id NOT IN (2,4,5,7,9,11,12,13,15,17,18)
GROUP BY color_id
```

Having these colors: 2,4,5,7,9,11,12,13,15,17,18
running that query, we discover that adding color_id:1 would "unlock" 2 paintings, and color_id:21 would unlock one